# React: React Facebook Login calling onsubmit twice?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a Sign In page using react, it allows the user to log in using Facebook, Google, or by using username and password. I just realize that every time I sign in using Facebook it coz to call the onSubmit twice. Only Facebook authentication causing this problem. Because of that, my backend validation is being called and return a res.json msg that will return an error msg on the frontend side. How can avoid that to happen if the user decided to use the Facebook login? I'm using react-facebook-login and react-google-login in terms of social media login.

**facebook button**

```
const handleFacebookLogin = async (res) => {
    dispatch(loginUser({ isFacebookId: res?.userID }));
  };

<FacebookLogin
              appId='code'
              callback={handleFacebookLogin}
              render={(renderProps) => (
                <button
                  onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                  className='w-full font-sans text-xs flex items-center focus:outline-none'
                >
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faFacebookF}
                    className='svg-size fill-current text-blue-600'
                  />
                  <span className='w-full'>Sign In with Facebook</span>
                </button>
              )}
            />
```

**Backend**
export const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
let { email, username, password, isFacebookId, isGoogleId } = req.body;

```
  try {
    if (isFacebookId) {
      const chkUser = await userModel.findOne({ isFacebookId: isFacebookId });
      if (chkUser) {
        if (!chkUser.isActive) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            msg: `The account is not yet activated.
            \n Please check your email for account activation link.`,
            activation: true,
          });
        } else {
          return res.status(200).json({
            _id: chkUser._id,
            email: chkUser.email,
            username: chkUser.username,
            name: chkUser.name,
            isAdmin: chkUser.isAdmin,
            msg: 'Login Success',
            tokenId: createRefreshToken(chkUser._id),
          });
        }
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({
          msg: 'This Facebook account is not register yet. Please register using this ',
          googleId: true,
        });
      }
    } else if (isGoogleId) {
      const chkUser = await userModel.findOne({ isGoogleId: isGoogleId });
      if (chkUser) {
        if (!chkUser.isActive) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            msg: `The account is not yet activated.
            \n Please check your email for account activation link.`,
            activation: true,
          });
        } else {
          return res.status(200).json({
            _id: chkUser._id,
            email: chkUser.email,
            username: chkUser.username,
            name: chkUser.name,
            isAdmin: chkUser.isAdmin,
            msg: 'Login Success',
            tokenId: createRefreshToken(chkUser._id),
          });
        }
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({
          msg: 'This Google account is not register yet. Please register using this ',
          googleId: true,
        });
      }
    } else if (!username && !email) {
      console.log('ta3');
      return res.status(400).json({
        msg: 'Please Provide a Username or Email',
        username: true,
      });
    } else if (!password) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        msg: 'Please Provide a Password',
        password: true,
      });
    } else {
      if (username) {
        const isEmail = (val) => {
          var data =
            /(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/;
          return data.test(val);
        };

        if (isEmail(username) === true) {
          email = username;
        }

        let chkUsernameEmail = email
          ? { email: username }
          : { username: username };

        const chkUser = await userModel.findOne(chkUsernameEmail);

        if (!chkUser) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            msg: 'Invalid Username or Email',
            username: true,
          });
        } else {
          if (!chkUser.isActive) {
            return res.status(400).json({
              msg: `The account is not yet activated.
              \n Please check your email for account activation link.`,
              activation: true,
            });
          } else {
            if (chkUser && (await chkUser.matchPassword(password))) {
              res.json({
                _id: chkUser._id,
                email: chkUser.email,
                username: chkUser.username,
                name: chkUser.name,
                isAdmin: chkUser.isAdmin,
                msg: 'Login Success',
                tokenId: createRefreshToken(chkUser._id),
              });
            } else {
              return res.status(400).json({
                msg: 'Invalid Password',
                password: true,
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ msg: error.message });
  }
```

Comment: show callback function

Comment: I already add the callback function.

Comment: pretty sure it has nothing got to do with the FacebookLogin component since I'm using the similar codes. You mentioned backend is called twice but you are not showing the codes that call your backend.

Comment: I also included the userLogin controller for my backend. The reason i said that the react-facebook-login is causing to call the onsubmit twice because I tried to add a console.log inside the if statement of !username && !email, console.log appeared but when i used the google login that situation is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think just disable the button on UI When calling the API.